# Problem with inline images after migration

Tags: media, migrations

We recently migrated from D7 to D8 (8.7.6). The migration went OK with the exception of nodes with inline images in the body fields (see the attached screen shot). The images were created in D7 with the CKEditor/Media Browser.

I have searched for contrib modules that can help with this issue but have not found anything yet.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: example of inline image problem]

[image: D7 filters]

[image: D8 filters]

Comment: Check your Input filters configuration on both sites (Text formats in D8). If you can recreate in D8 all the input filters used on the format you used in D7 nodes, and order them in the same order too. Post screenshots of the relevant text input configuration in both D7 and D8.

Comment: Thanks.  I have included screen shots of the filters for D7 and D8 in the original post.  We tried reordering the filters in D8 but no luck yet.

Comment: Find out which module is responsible for the first two options in the D7 filter you're using, and see if you can install and configure it the same way in D8. Then the saved text will be read and evaluated in the same way, correctly interpreting the code and showing images.

Comment: It looks like all the same media related modules are installed/enabled on the D8 site, but the filters are labeled quite differently.  Thanks for the suggestion though.